# Merging custom and default truststore in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

I have requirement to use default and custom trust store in the tomcat application. I have added addEnv.sh with following

`JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<trustStorePath> \
         -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<trustStorePassword> \
         -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=<keystorePassword> \
         -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=<keystorePath> \
         -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=JKS \
         -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=JKS"`

Application is able to connect using the above custom truststore but fails to make call where default truststore should be used.

Is there any way to merge custom and default truststore in the tomcat startup script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only possible to set one truststore using JVM variable `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore`. You can import into your custom truststore the desired certificates of the default JVM truststore at `$JAVA_HOME/JRE/lib/security/cacerts`